# Generating function of the number of integral solutions to the equation: $\sum_i x_i=n$ with additional restrictions on partial sums.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, generating-functions

Find the generating function of the number of non-negative integer solutions to the equation: $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8=n$ where $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$ is even and $x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8$ is odd.

I have a possible solution but I don't know if it is right.

The generating function of the number of non-negative integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=k$ is given by:$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}$$

Now we want to get the function s.t the coefficients of the odd terms are $0$ and similarly another function s.t the coefficients of the even terms are $0$.

The functions can be derived as follows:$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^4}\right)$$ and $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^4}\right)$$

Hence, the final generating function we want would be:$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^4}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^4}\right)=\\\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^8}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^8}\right)$$

Is this solution correct?

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by "non-integral solutions?" I would assume that means non-integer, but then it doesn't make much sense to start speaking of $x_i$ being even or odd...

Comment: no their sum is even or odd

Comment: Oh, I see. My bad!

Comment: You were right. Sorry changed the statement

Comment: Your solution is correct (with the edit to the statement).